# Skew Symmetric Matrix with condition

Tags: skew-symmetric-matrices

If A is 2*2 skew symmetric matrix with $$A^2=A$$, Then A=0 $$$$
My attempt was by assuming the matrix A and substituting the squaring condition and the condition of
skew symmetric and got system of equations but I couldn't solve it.I look forward to your comments.

Comment: For skew symmetric matrices  $I\pm A$ is invertible.

Comment: This is not true. Take the identity matrix over $\Bbb F_2$. Then $A^2=A$, and $A$ is skew-symmetric but nonzero.

Comment: As one of the Answers posted quickly shows, the steps you outlined should have led directly to solving the problem (for a *real* skew-symmetric matrix).  Merely stating "but I couldn't solve it" is not the kind of context for the problem that is needed for good Questions at Math.SE.

Comment: Dietrich Burde....The identity matrix is not skew-symmetric

Comment: @AlKhuzai:  In characteristic two the identity matrix is skew-symmetric.  You failed to state that your matrix entries are drawn from the real numbers (or another domain that is not characteristic two).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A=A^2=(-A)^2=(A^T)^2=A^TA^T=(AA)^T=A^T=-A$$

This is valid in all cases where $\mathrm{char}(F)\ne2$. It can be easily prooved by defenition, and does not matter on size of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & a  \\
    -a       & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A^2=A$ implies

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -a^2       & 0  \\
    0       & -a^2 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & a  \\
    -a       & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $a=0$ and $A=O$